# What does "that could" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, auxiliary-verbs

For example:

> A plan **that could**

I see this "that could" part (with no complement) everywhere, as in:

> The Little Engine that Could.

What does this phrase mean?

Comment: Too vague I guess, some more context would help the question.

Comment: The word *that* can be used in several different ways, so the expression won't always mean the same thing. The **that could** in _"That could be the key to solve this mystery"_ doesn't necessarily function the same as the **that could** in _"Flight 322 is the one that could get us to Portland on time."_ This might be "too broad".

Comment: @kih1930 Do you really see this everywhere?  I can't think of any other examples like **(noun phrase)** **+** ***that could***.  To me, it seems fairly idiosyncratic, and I'd always imagined it was specific to **The Little Engine that Could**.

Comment: @snailboat I see it often enough that it seems worth having the question; I've always thought of *The Little Engine* when I've heard it, but it's one of those shorthand expressions that's become more or less free-floating.

Comment: @Mistu4u That's the point: what “the X that could” means as a standalone phrase, not when it's “X that could VERB”.

Comment: @Gilles, Actually I never came across with such constructs; if they exist at all, then it would make a great question. I voted to reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**That could** (or **that can**) by itself is an idiomatic usage that has an implied verb that is something like *succeed*. *The Little Engine that Could* keeps repeating the phrase "I think I can [make it over the mountain]", and the headline you mention means that this is "the plan that could [solve the problem]".

Comment: Is “The X that could” always (derived from) an allusion to *The Little Engine that Could*, or did the phrase exist before that?

Comment: I don't understand “the plan that could” as meaning “the plan that has a chance of solving the problem [and we should try it and see]” or “the plan that is capable of solving the problem [if nothing else gets in the way]” or “the plan that is sure to solve the problem [provided it is adopted]” (which one do you think it means, by the way?). I thought that “the X that could” implied perseverance — a plan that's been proposed times and times again, or that has spent a long time in being carried out.

Comment: @Gilles I can't recall ever having seen this use, but if I ever did see it, I think I'd interpret it the same way you do here.  It think it'd have to be using the title as a phrasal template (a *snowclone*).